# SDL_SetVideoMode vs SDL_CreateRGBSurface

Tags: sdl, sdl-1.2

Should be a simple question for SDL experts. I am confused about the following two seemingly equivalent functions and wondering when to use which

```
SDL_Surface * SDL_SetVideoMode (int width, int height, int bpp, Uint32 flags);
SDL_Surface * SDL_CreateRGBSurface (Uint32 flags,
        int width, int height, int depth,
        Uint32 Rmask, Uint32 Gmask, Uint32 Bmask, Uint32 Amask);
```

What's the fundamental difference between the above two?

It's mentioned [here](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_CreateRGBSurface) that SDL_CreateRGBSurface has to be called *after* SDL_SetVideoMode. Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_SetVideoMode` creates a window. This surface will be visible on the screen.

`SDL_CreateRGBSurface` creates off-screen image. `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` is used, for example, when you load images from disk. You need to blit it to the screen in order to see them.

Comment: Just noticed that you answered it first. Thank you

Comment: @Saptarshi you are supposed to accept the most helpful answer, not necessary the first.

Answer (score 4):

They are completely different functions.

`SDL_SetVideoMode` creates the video surface (a.k.a. application screen) and show it to the user.

`SDL_CreateRGBSurface` creates an empty surface.

After calling `SDL_SetVideoMode`, if successful, a screen will be shown to the user and you will have (returned by the function, or by calling `SDL_GetVideoSurface`) the video surface, the screen surface.

`SDL_CreateRGBSurface` simply creates an empty surface that you can play with it.

Some usage example would be: your application starts and you initialize the video, then you create an empty surface and manipulate it somehow, and finally you blit it to the video surface and the user will see the surface that you manipulated (remember to flip the screen surface, `SDL_Flip`).

It's important to know what a `SDL_Surface` is. Since you don't asked I assume you know.

Comment: +1 This explanation really helped. Thanks! However, I am now facing a [related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249998/cannot-display-yuv-overlay-on-sdl-surface). Would you care to take a look if time permits?