# Cannot display YUV Overlay on SDL_Surface

Tags: sdl

I want to modify `ffplay` by hiding its SDL video player window. Rather, I want to grab the overlay as pixel-by-pixel bitmaps to be used elsewhere in my program.

Now `ffplay` can be simplified as below:

1. Create `SDL_Surface *screen` from `SDL_SetVideoMode()`
2. Create `SDL_Overlay *bmp` from `SDL_CreateYUVOverlay()` and associate it with `screen`

   repeat until video ends
3. Decode movie frames and populate bmp
4. Render bmp onto screen using `SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay()`

Following hints from [this article](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_GUI), I have replaced Step 1 as below:

```
/* Don't want video player window showing on screen
* int flags = SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_ASYNCBLIT|SDL_HWACCEL;
* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(w, h, 24, flags);
*/
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
rmask = 0xff000000;
gmask = 0x00ff0000;
bmask = 0x0000ff00;
amask = 0x00000000;
#else
rmask = 0x000000ff;
gmask = 0x0000ff00;
bmask = 0x00ff0000;
amask = 0x00000000;
#endif
screen = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, h, 24, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
```

and Step 4 as

```
SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(bmp, &rect);
SDL_SaveBMP(screen, filenameN); N++;
```

Issue:
If I modify only Step 4, the bitmap files are getting saved properly which is what I want, except that the video playing window is visible. On the other hand, if I modify Step 2 as well, the window gets successfully hidden the bitmaps are all blacked out.

I am new to SDL, so apart from just the solution, an explanation on why my approach does not work will be helpful.

Comment: Try using [dummy](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlenvvars.html) video driver.

Comment: Adding `SDL_putenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy")` solves my problem. Thank you @Banthar. Post it as an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 0):

Use `SDL_putenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy");` to use the [dummy](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_envvars) video driver, which produces no output.